# swig-3.0.12 generates python2 style import statements

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, swig

I am converting a large swig based codebase to python3. My current problem is that in-sub directories swig generates import statements as: 'import xxx' vs 'import dir_name.xxx'. The former causes import failures in python3.

Comment: This is very vague.  Please make a simple example showing the problem and the SWIG command used to generate the extension and the error message.  See [mcve].  Also check `swig -python -help` to see if any of the Python-specific options apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate proper python3 imports, one has to define modules with package parameter:

```
%module(package="package_name") module_name
vs
%module module_name
```

Unfortunately, I could not find command-line or environment options to supply the package name at compile time.